# Azure pipeline concatenating variable names and accessing new variable value

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

In my Azure pipeline I have 2 vairables `$name1 = hello $name2 = world`. Those variable value change at run time.

I can concatenate those 2 variable value which will create $helloworld variable.

How do I access $helloworld value? $Helloworld variable is also declared in the pipeline

I'm trying to pass the value of this variable as an argument to the powershell

The following doesn't seem to work `$($(name1)$(name2))`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to refer it as,

Let's say you had  $name1 = 'hello' and $name2 = 'world'.

```
$($name1)$($name2) = 'helloworld'
```

Comment: It doesn't work. ($name1)($name2) makes 'helloworld. And now I need to access value in $helloworld

Answer (score 0):

You may use $helloworld = "$name1 $name2", please have a try.

The update:

Please have a try with the commands below:

```
$name1 = "h" 
$name2 = "w"

New-Variable -Name "${name1}${name2}" -Value 'helloword' -Force

$hw
```

Comment: $name1$name2 create variable name $helloworld and I want to access value of $helloworld. When I use $(helloworld) and hard code the name of that variable it works. But if I use concatenation it doesn't work

Comment: @EkaterinaGiuliani, please have a try with the command below:

$name1 = "h" 
$name2 = "w"

New-Variable -Name "${name1}${name2}" -Value 'helloword' -Force

$hw

Comment: @EkaterinaGiuliani, since the comment is not so clear, so I update the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: I'm trying to access this variable from the pipeline. $name1 and $name2 are variables in pipeline that change at the run time. I want to concatenate they value to make name or another variable and then access its value

Comment: You may try to use this command: Get-Variable -Name "${name1}${name2}". If you want to access the $helloword value by expression but not by command, you can use New-Variable -Name "test" -Value (Get-Variable -Name "${name1}${name2}").Value -Force and then we can access the value via $test.

Comment: Hi @EkaterinaGiuliani, may I know if the answer I post in last comment yesterday help your problem ?

Comment: No it hasn't. I've tried to do that New-Variable -Name "test" -Value (Get-Variable -Name "${name1}${name2}").Value -Force. But I'm trying to access env variable from the pipeline so I need to somehow append $env

Answer (score 0):

> Azure pipeline concatenating variable names and accessing new variable value

AFAIK, this issue is about nested variables rather than the concatenate variable.

As you test, you can get the `helloworld` by the `($name1)($name2)`, but we could not  access value in `$helloworld`  by the nested variable `$($(name1)$(name2))`.

That is because the value of nested variables (like `$($(name1)$(name2))`) are not yet supported in the build pipelines at this moment.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Hope this helps.